# Linux Interrupts

Tags: linux, interrupt

I'm trying to  write my own interrupt controller but I'm having some difficulties finding good documentation. Where can I find some information about interrupt management in Linux?

---

To be more specific, I have a simple interrupt controller, with enable, clear and status registers, and I'm trying to write a driver to control it.

I've found some documentation and some examples, but nothing very helpful.

Comment: and interrupt controller is a piece of hardware, not something you can write.  You will have to be more specific if you want an answer.

Comment: **[LDD3](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)** Chapter 10.

Comment: Ok, could you instead tell us which part you don't understand? It's impossible to try and guess what you know or not.

Answer (score 1):

The words "good documentation" is very abstract.

IMHO, I have some links for you:

- http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch09.html
- http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~krj/os/lectures/L07-LinuxEvents.pdf
- http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/dd/interrupts.html